# How to contact Google Support for MarketPlace support

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sendgrid

1. Why are there two products of sendgrid on Google Cloud MarketPlace? What are the different?
   [image]
2. A few months ago, I signed up for "SendGrid Marketing Campaigns".
   Now I could not login to my sendgrid account. I contacted sendgrid support. Here is what they said:

   Hello,

   Thanks for reaching out to SendGrid Support!

   It looks like your account was disabled on the Google Cloud Platform side, which is why you are unable to log into the account. You will need to reach out to GCP support in order to re-enable the account on their side.

   I apologize for the inconvenience.

   Let me know if you have any other questions. We're more than happy to help!

   Best,

I can not find where and how/why GCP disabled my account. 
However, I check my gcp project, they are running. I think the sendgrid support person implies that GCP disabled my Sendgrid account.
However, it seems GCP does not.
[image]

I am on Bronze plan of GCP support. It seems I can not email or call to GCP to get support.

Anybody get the same problem?
Where can I get GCP support for sendgrid account problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a customer support question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 2):

Sendgrid offers multiple services, the email API allows you to send individual emails and handles all of the aspects like bounced messages, unsubscribe, etc. The marketing campaign offers many of the same features but also allows you to use templated messages, do A/B testing, schedule message sending, and perform analytics.

My guess is that your free trial expired and you don't have a billing account associated with your account, or if you do it has an expired credit card. If you do still have credits some features require a linked credit card anyway, primarily for features that can quickly generate costs.

Bronze support is allowed to contact GCP Support, but only if they're still on the free trial. After the trial has passed you'll need to register for an active level of support to ask technical questions. Do keep in mind that all billing related questions will get help regardless of your support level. So if you're unsure if the free trial is your problem, contact [billing support](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_billing), and they'll likely be able to give you more info.

Answer (score 0):

I did have the same problem as you, the issue was my Credit card expired, so your issue is billing issue, when you fix it, **SendGrid Marketing Campaigns** will be enabled again.

As `@FridayPush` mention.